# SQL subtract two independent counts

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a rather complex SQL statement I'm attempting to write, and not sure how to do it.

Basically, I'm looking for the most active people in a chatroom (where my chat is stored in an SQL table), but MINUS the number of times they say a particular message TIMES a multiplier on the subtraction.

Here is the "base" query which works fine to find out how often someone chats:

```
SELECT users.name, count(*) as count1, users.flag2, users.flag1
            FROM chat
            INNER JOIN users
            ON chat.userid=users.id
            WHERE channel=$channel
            GROUP BY userid
            ORDER BY count DESC
            LIMIT 100;
```

This query will tell me how many times a user says a particular message I am looking to subtract off a **multiple of**:

```
SELECT userid, count(*) as count2
            FROM chat
            WHERE channel=$channel AND text = '[some message]'
            GROUP BY userid
```

What I'm looking for is the first query to have "count" actually equal to "**count1 - count2 * 10**".  I'm having a rather tough time figuring out how to compose these two queries into one.  I will be using the resulting "value" as the ORDER BY/LIMIT clause, so I need SQL to actually do this calculation instead of doing it in multiple queries...

Comment: can't you just reverse the condition of the second, and put it in the first query like *WHERE channel=$channel AND text <> '[some message]'* ?

Comment: No because there's a multiplier in play.  It's 10 times the second query result, otherwise yes that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   SELECT T1.name,(count1 - 10* COALESCE( count2,0) ) as NetCount
   FROM
    (
            SELECT userid,users.name, count(*) as count1
            FROM chat
            INNER JOIN users
            ON chat.userid=users.id
            WHERE channel=$channel
            GROUP BY userid,users.name
            ORDER BY count DESC
            LIMIT 100;
     ) as T1

  LEFT JOIN

  (
            SELECT userid, count(*) as count2
            FROM chat
            WHERE channel=$channel AND text = '[some message]'
            GROUP BY userid
  ) as T2

  ON T1.userid=T2.userid
```

Comment: One problem I have here is that if no one has "text == [some message]", then they are not selected at all by this.  I want anyone who doesn't have text=[some message] to have count2 as 0.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similer issue where count(*) is coming out as 0 when in reality it should be bigger,

```sql
select count(*) from unified_audit_trail 
where event_timestamp<='02-DEC-22'
MINUS 
select count(*) from unified_audit_trail 
where event_timestamp<='30-NOV-22';
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33322126)